# Sed delete everything except text between 2 words in file

Tags: linux, file, sed, data-manipulation

I have a file that includes an XML file and i need everything deleted except the text that starts with

```
<?xml version="1.0
```

and ends with

```
</martif>
```

Thanks you

I tried

```
sed '/<?xml version=/,$!d' file > result.txt
```

to delete everything until xml part but to delete from `</martif>` to the end i do not know how to achieve that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

USe `</martif>` as the end of the range to print.

```
sed -n '/<?xml version=/,/<\/martif>/p' file.xml > result.txt
```